# Mongoose Getter/Setter Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a MERN stack that's using RTK Query to get and pass data. I'm trying to build a setter on my data, but whenever I use findOneAndUpdate or UpdateOne, neither seem to run the setter. Virtuals seems to kick back errors about reading undefined variables that are used to build the new key even though I used an if statement to check that. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Here's how my setter is built:

```
damage: {
      diceCount: Number,
      diceValue: Number,
      diceShort: {
        type: String,
        set: function () {
          let diceShortValue = null
          if (this.diceCount && this.diceValue) {
            diceShortValue = `${this.diceCount}d${this.diceValue}`
          }
          return diceShortValue
        },
      },
      versatileDiceValue: Number,
      versatileDiceCount: Number,
      bonusDamage: Number,
      damageType: {
        type: [
          {
            id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Builder' },
            name: String,
            value: String,
          },
        ],
        default: undefined,
      },
    },
```

And at the end of my schema I added this options

```
export const itemSchema = new Schema(
  {
....
},
  {
    toJSON: { setters: true, minimize: true },
    toObject: { setters: true, minimize: true },
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema)
```

My API setup looks like

```
export const updateItem = async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.body

  if (!_id) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Item ID is required' })
  }

  const updatedItem = req.body

  const item = await Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, updatedItem, {
    new: true,
  }).exec()

  if (!item) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Item not found' })
  }

  res.json(`'${item.value}' updated`)
}
```

What's even more odd is if I have the {getters: true} option set, I get an error in my RTK side saying

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'unit' in 40

I tried using a virtual getter to build the key instead of a setter, but when diceValue/diceCount didn't exist, it was giving me an error. My getter was built exactly as the setter using the conditional.

Comment: Error is not in this part of your code

Comment: I have no idea where else it would be. The variables it's using to set the key value exist. I confirmed it in MongoDB. So it should be getting set here and it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has posed me problems in the past with setters and custom logic, such as checking the value of other properties in the update document. The key to understanding here is two things:

1. The setter will only run in a `findOneAndUpdate` if a value of `diceShort` is passed in the update document. If the update document does not have a `diceShort` property then forget about the setter working. That is expected because you are not updating `diceShort` so why should it run any setter or validation, right? I would just pass an empty string in your case because it looks like your intention is to either set it to `null` or doing a concatenation.
2. Your `this` keyword in a standard function declaration at the setter stage does not point to the Model or document, it points to the Query object so to access `diceCount` and `diceValue` you need to step through to the `_update` property. That is where they are stored. Update like so and hopefully it solves your issue and stops you pulling your hair out all night:

```js
//...
    diceCount: Number,
    diceValue: Number,
    diceShort: {
        type: String,
        set: function(){
            let diceShortValue = null
            if (this._update.diceCount && this._update.diceValue) {
                diceShortValue = `${this._update.diceCount}d${this._update.diceValue}`
            }
            return diceShortValue;
        },
    },
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you’re saying, if let’s say diceCount and diceValue aren’t updated, it won’t read them even if I’m sending back the whole object into findOneAndUpdate? Let me try the _update fix and I’ll report back.

Comment: Made the changes, went and updated the document, it didn't add the key-value. Does the key have to exist first for it to set it? In my update API, I'm sending the whole document back so I know the key-values being used exist for the one I'm testing.

Comment: So when you do a `findOneAndUpdate` the validators and setters will only run on values being passed in the update object. In your case `diceCount`, `diceValue` and `diceShort` need to be in the update document. If your document doesn't have them to start with you can add `upsert: true` right after `new: true,`. You update document might look like `{diceCount: 1, diceValue: 2, diceShort: ''}`

Comment: Got it. I can confirm both the old document and the new document do have them. This is a new key-value I'm adding to an existing document. I really wish the mongoose docs were more clear on how to use these.

Comment: Sorry, just read my message back, `upsert: true` will add a new document if there is no match on `_id` so if you already have the document and just don't have these new keys then you don't need the `upsert: true`.

Comment: Just tried removing that and still didn't work. I'm sure it's something I have set up incorrectly, I just can't figure it out. I've also tried using updateOne instead and still didn't work. I'm using the latest version of mongoose (7.6.2). I may just end up having the my state reducer in react create it or something before passing it if I can't get this to work.

Comment: Try this `const update = await Item.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: _id}, {diceCount: 1,diceValue: 2, diceShort: '' }, {new: true});`

Comment: It definitely updated the diceCount, diceValue, and added diceShort with null as the value. I tried removing the _updated from the setter in the model and same results. I changed the diceValue on the second test to ensure it is changing.

Comment: It's `_update` not `_updated` just in case you had a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that wrong in my comment, but did have it right in the model.

Comment: Just for a sanity check can you add `console.log('update document=', this._update);` right after `let diceShortValue = null` in your schema and then do an update as I want your code to work. What does it output?

Comment: I really do appreciate all of the help, by the way! It output

`update document= { damage: { diceCount: 1, diceValue: 3, diceShort: '' } }`

Comment: Ahh, I see now. In your schema you need to do `this._update.damage.diceCount`  and `this._update.damage.diceValue`. Do that in all 4 places you have them.

Comment: Hallelujah! That did it! I can't believe I overlooked that. I totally understand why it wasn't seeing it. I was telling it to look at a key that never existed because I forgot to add the parent key.

Comment: Bingo. You are correct. Have a good evening and good luck with your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255650/discussion-between-mpiland-and-jqueeny).